# Implementation of a NOT gate with two transistors - Why not one?

Tags: transistors, logic-gates

I just encountered this implementation of a NOT gate:

[image: Not Gate with 2 transistors]

My question is: Why do we need the lower transistor? Why can't we do this:

[image: Proposed Not gate]

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

...because to represent logical 0 you need (close to) 0 Volts and not just a floating output.

Comment: Then why not connect the drain of the transistor to the ground?

Comment: Drain is the output. If you connect it to GND it will be *always* 0 (and if you turn on the single transistor you will have a short between V(1) and GND). Though you could use a pull-down resistor from drain to GND.

Comment: To connect the drain to ground you'd need to disconnect it when the upper transistor is on to avoid a short, possibly with something like another transistor? Hence CMOS is born :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers, the NOT gate CAN be implemented using a MOSFET and a resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2S8XU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But the problem here is the current that will be constantly flowing while `In` is high. The transistor will be then conducting, effectively closing the circuit with current around \$V(1)/R_1\$.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, what pulls the output down to ground? Essentially when the PFET is off, you will be left with the output signal floating. If it is required to drive another logic gate for example, then it will not be able to sink current to discharge any parasitic capacitance of the next stage.

CMOS is what is known as 'fully restored logic' because you have two transistors which can pull to opposite power rails meaning that the output voltage levels are equal to the power rails.

This is advantageous behaviour if for example you need to chain multiple CMOS devices together. Without fully restored logic, then your digital signal will get lower and lower with each gate until the signal gets corrupted (a 1 is no longer high enough voltage to represent a 1). This need far outweighs the space cost of the extra transistor.

Answer (score 2):

Actually both varieties are used, two transistor and one-transistor (although the latter is not how you drew it).

The first is called push-pull[totem-pole also called active pullup], and the second is called open-drain.

Push-pull outputs can both source (supply Vcc) and sink (ground) outputs.  Open-drain can only sink outputs.  The Vcc supply must come from somewhere else (usually a pull-up resistor).

The 74HC04, with six inverters, is an example of push-pull outputs.  The 74HC05, also with six inverters is an example of open-drain outputs.

Here is the output stage of each inverter on the 74HC05:

[image]

When the input is ground, the output is floating.  When the input is high, the output is grounded.

There are two common applications of open-drain outputs:

1) Connecting more than one output to the same line. This is called a wired-OR. For example, you may have a normally high reset pin on a device, which is reset from both a microcontroller pin and another source, say a pushbutton. The reset pin is tied high with a pull-up resistor. The microcontroller is configured as an open-drain output. The pushbutton is tied to ground when pushed. If either the microcontroller pulls its output to 0, or the pushbutton is pressed, the device will be reset.

2) Controlling devices connected to different supply voltages. Say you have a relay that requires 20 mA, but a voltage of 5 volts. But your microcontroller output can only drive pins up to its power supply (VCC) voltage of 3.3v. With an open-drain output, you can connect one side of the relay to 5 V, and the other to the output pin of the microcontroller. When the output of the microcontroller in is 1, nothing happens (again, acts like the pin is disconnected). When it is set to 0, this grounds the bottom side of the relay completing the circuit and operating the relay.

Answer (score 1):

You need something to both source and sink current.  Transistor gates look like capacitors and they have to be charged and discharged.  If you can't sink current, then the only way the transistor will turn off is to wait for the charge in the gate to leak out, which could take quite a long time.  It is possible to replace one transistor with a resistor, but resistors take up a HUGE amount of silicon area as opposed to transistors, and the output drive characteristics will be asymmmetric.  The static power consumption will also become state dependent.  Using another transistor results in symmetric output drive and low static power consumption.

NMOS logic generally uses only the lower transistor, plus a pull up of either a resistor or a weak transistor configured as an always-on pull-up.  CMOS logic uses transistors on both sides, sized to be symmetrical in drive strength.  CMOS also fully regenerates the logic level after each gate.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it can be done with one transistor. What you drew needs a way to pull the output down to 0v when the transistor is off, a resistor will do that.
The two transistor version has the advantage that it uses very little power when the output is either high or low. The one transistor version you drew will use some power when the output is high [current thru the required pull-down resistor].
To reduce this power you would want to make this resistor a large value [lower current], but then the current available to discharge capacitive loads would be reduced,making the transition time from output high to low longer [slower]. If you make the resistor smaller it gets faster but uses more power.
The two transistor version gets around this by having low static power and fast tpdHL and tpdHL times.